# Getting warehouse missing error while creating dynamic tables in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i am getting the error:-

> Failed to refresh dynamic table with refresh_trigger INITIAL at data_timestamp 1709729749008 because of the error: SQL compilation error: Target table failed to refresh: Dynamic Table 'db_one.schema_one.table_one' could not be refreshed because warehouse 'COMPUTE_WH' is missing.

while i am using ACCOUNTADMIN role and had all the privileges on this warehouse.

However, i have created the same dynamic table 1 week before with the same warehouse then it was created successfully, this time only i have added a new column the re run the query but getting missing warehouse error also now it is showing same error for other dynamic tables.

Also i have tried with other warehouses but still getting same error.

Comment: Hi - please update your question with the DDL for the table, evidence for which role owns the table and for the permissions that role has on the warehouse

Comment: Recheck your permissions and/or existence of that warehouse.  Clearly something has changed there.